# How to get the first empty cell in a googlesheet

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using below Nodejs code to insert some text to google spreadsheet, what I need to know is:

How can I make the code detect the first empty cell in specific column , for example first empty cell in column A, so I can start add my text to it, (or last cell which has value in column A, so I can start add my text after it)

Here you are existing code:

```
const mySpreadSheetId = 'mySheetId';
const range = 'Sheet2!A10';
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: mySpreadSheetId,
        range: range,
        valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
        resource: {range: 'Sheet2!A10',
            majorDimension: 'ROWS',
              values: [["some Text"]]}     
    } ,(err, resp) => {

        if (err) {
            console.log('Data Error :', err);
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(resp);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to put a value to the 1st empty cell in the specific column.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for the Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

In order to know the 1st empty row in the specific column, at first, the values are required to be retrieved. The flow of this modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the values of the specific column you want to retrieve the the 1st empty cell.
2. Retrieve the 1st empty row.
3. Put the value to the cell using the retrieved 1st empty row.

#### Modified script:

Please modify the script in `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { ### })` as follows. Before you run the script, please set the variables of `mySpreadSheetId` and `sheetName`. In this modified script, the 1st empty cell of the column "A" is retrieved and the value of `some Text` is put to the retrieved cell.

```
const mySpreadSheetId = 'mySheetId';
const sheetName = "Sheet2";

sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
  {
    auth: jwtClient,
    spreadsheetId: mySpreadSheetId,
    range: `${sheetName}!A:A`
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    const data = res.data.values;
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (!data[i][0]) break;
    }
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(
      {
        auth: jwtClient,
        spreadsheetId: mySpreadSheetId,
        range: `${sheetName}!A${i + 1}`,
        valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
        resource: {
          majorDimension: "ROWS",
          values: [["some Text"]]
        }
      },
      (err, resp) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Data Error :", err);
          reject(err);
        }
        resolve(resp);
      }
    );
  }
);
```

#### Note:

- Above modified script retrieves the 1st empty cell of the specific column. In this case, for example, when the values are set like `1, 2, , 4, 5`, the value is put to the 3rd cell. If you want to append the value to the specific column, please modify above script as follows.

  - From:

    ```
    let i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (!data[i][0]) break;
    }
    ```
  - To:

    ```
    let i = data.length;
    ```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Great, it woks perfectly, ありがとうございます　たないけさん

Comment: if I want to return a text if resolve(resp); can I write return ("successfully works"); or it will not executed?

Comment: @usama sulaiman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the additional question, in your script, how about modifying from `resolve(resp);` to `resolve("successfully works");`? By this, when the request has no error, `successfully works` is returned. But I'm not sure about your whole script. So if this was not the direct solution, I apologize. At that time, can you post it as new question by including the detail information? By this, it will help users including me help to think of the issue and solution.

Comment: I had a small issue, so I added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59125963/dialogflow-agent-add-not-working-with-promise

Comment: @usama sulaiman Thank you for replying. I will check it. And when I could find the solution, I would like to post an answer.