# Dialogflow agent.add not working with promise

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to return data from spreadsheet, the code is working fine, and data appears in the log, but `agent.add` not working, as expected.

I need is to make the dialogflow to response and return the data which I get from spreadsheet.

What happen is that in one position of the code, the dialogflow `agent.add` working as expected, but it's not returning the data which I get form the spreadsheet, see this part:

> `agent.add("status code inside: "+ myCode); // agent.add working, but
>   myCode variable not showing the data which returned from spreadsheet, it only shows the original value "XmXm"`

In the other position of the code, `agent.add` not working, even I can see the spreadsheet data in the log, (I tried with and without `return` before `agent.add`) see this part

> `return agent.add("status code outside:"+ value);  // function
>   agent.add whether or not I add return before it`

Note that I tried many solution which provided in stackoverflow, but I still can't fix it, below is my full code:

```js
  function sheetPromiseHandelerGet(orderNum){
   const jwtClient = authSheet();     
let getSheetPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
  const mySpreadSheetId = 'SHEET_ID';
  const sheetName = "SHEET_NAME";
  let myCode = "XmXm"; // give myCode a string value for testing
  let testFirst = 0;
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(
    {
      auth: jwtClient,
      spreadsheetId: mySpreadSheetId,
      range: `${sheetName}!A:H`
    },
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      const data = res.data.values;
      let i = 0;
      for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (orderNum == data[i][0]){
          myCode = `myCode: Order details: ${data[i][1]}`;
          resolve(myCode);
        } 
      }
    }
  );
  agent.add("status code inside: "+ myCode); // agent.add working, but myCode variable not is "XmXm"
});
   return getSheetPromise.then(function(value) {
 console.log(value); // the value (which is the result comes from spreadsheet) appears correctly in the debugger, 
 return agent.add("status code outside:" value);  // function agent.add whether or not I add return before it 
});
  }
  
  
  function orderStatusHandel(agent){
const detailsNum = agent.parameters.detailsNum;
sheetPromiseHandelerGet(detailsNum);
  }
  
  function authSheet(){
//
  }
```

I'll be greatly appreciating your help!

Comment: I cannot understand about `myCode variable not is "XmXm"`. Can I ask you about the result you expect? By the way, which do you want to use Google Apps Script or Node.js?

Comment: @Tanaike I'm sorry for any confusion, the XmXm is only initial value, to check whether or not this value will be override with the new value which comes from spreadsheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the modified scripts as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after many tries, I found the answer, which is very simple, I figure that I need to add `return` before calling the main function `sheetPromiseHandelerGet(detailsNum)` which calls the `sheetPromiseHandelerGet(orderNum)`, that's all

so if you look to end of my code in the question, instead of

```
function orderStatusHandel(agent){
    const detailsNum = agent.parameters.detailsNum;
    sheetPromiseHandelerGet(detailsNum); //return is missing
}
```

it must be

```
function orderStatusHandel(agent){
    const detailsNum = agent.parameters.detailsNum;
    return sheetPromiseHandelerGet(detailsNum); //return has been added
}
```

Other than this, it's better to make other change:

```
resolve(myCode);
```

to be

```
resolve(agent.add(myCode));
```

I hope that can help anyone has the same problem

Answer (score 1):

- You want to use `myCode` retrieved from Spreadsheet with `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get()` at `agent.add("status code inside: " + myCode);`.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.
- You have already been able to get values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just on of several possible answers.

### Modification points:

- `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get()` works with the asynchronous process. By this, in your script, `myCode` of `agent.add("status code inside: "+ myCode);` is always the initial value (in your case, it's `XmXm`.).
- In your script, `sheets.spreadsheets.values.get` is run in `new Promise()`. So `value` of `getSheetPromise.then(function(value) {})` is the retrieved value.

### Pattern 1:

#### Modified script:

If you want to use `agent.add("status code inside: "+ myCode);` in `new Promise` in your script, how about the following modification?

From:

```
if (orderNum == data[i][0]){
  myCode = `myCode: Order details: ${data[i][1]}`;
  resolve(myCode);
}
```

To:

```
if (orderNum == data[i][0]){
  myCode = `myCode: Order details: ${data[i][1]}`;
  agent.add("status code inside: "+ myCode);
  resolve(myCode);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

#### Modified script:

As other pattern, how about the following modification? In this case, please modify `getSheetPromise` in your script as follows.

```
let getSheetPromise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  const mySpreadSheetId = "SHEET_ID";
  const sheetName = "SHEET_NAME";
  let myCode = "XmXm";
  // let testFirst = 0; // It seems that this is not used.
  const res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    auth: jwtClient,
    spreadsheetId: mySpreadSheetId,
    range: `${sheetName}!A:H`
  });
  const data = res.data.values;
  let i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (orderNum == data[i][0]) {
      myCode = `myCode: Order details: ${data[i][1]}`;
      resolve(myCode);
      // break; // When there are several same values of `orderNum` in the column "A", please use this line.
    }
  }
  agent.add("status code inside: " + myCode);
});
```

- In this case, for example, when there are several same values of `orderNum` in the column "A", `myCode` of `agent.add("status code inside: " + myCode)` is the value of the last same row, while `myCode` of `resolve(myCode)` is the 1st same row. If you want to 1st one, please remove `//` of `// break;`.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaika san for your hlep, I greatly appreciating your effort and help, solving the problem was in another part of code , I post the answer below

Comment: @usama sulaiman Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

try `return agent.add("status code outside:"+value);`I think '+' is missing.

Comment: Yes, it is just a typo because I was adding it between ` `, but I change it to be " ", but sure it still not working

Comment: I solve the problem , it was in a missing return on last function, I posted the answer below